# tween in the shortest direction of a looping range tween.js

Tags: tween.js

I have two radains. range is 0 to 6.28319.
When I take A and i want to make it tween to B. I want it to go the shortest distance.
Example.

If A is 1 and B is 5. Its faster for it to tween, by going
1, .9, .8, .7, .6, .5, .4, .3, .2, .1, 0, 6.18... and so forth till it reachs 5.

Any Idea how to use Tween.js and make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

couldnt figure it out, but in my case this works. Because its out if it goes outside the range.

This will do

A is 1
B is 5 //Goal

1 + 6.28319 = 7.28319
So it will start at 7.28319 and tween back to 5. I am out of my range but in my case its ok to take this short cut because I am  using three.js and it knows what 7.28319 is.

```
let azimuthalRad = ((controls.getAzimuthalAngle() % 6.28319) + 6.28319) % 6.28319; //A
let goalYawRad = THREE.Math.degToRad(trackObjects[trackCount - 1].yaw + 30); //B
let startTweenRad = 0;
if (azimuthalRad <= goalYawRad) {
    if (goalYawRad - azimuthalRad <= Math.abs(goalYawRad - (azimuthalRad + 6.28319))) {
        startTweenRad = azimuthalRad;
    }
    else {
        startTweenRad = (azimuthalRad + 6.28319);
    }
}
else {
    if (azimuthalRad - goalYawRad <= Math.abs(goalYawRad - (azimuthalRad - 6.28319))) {
        startTweenRad = azimuthalRad;
    }
    else {
        startTweenRad = azimuthalRad - 6.28319;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but what i ended up with worked for my purposes.